# Find the infinite sum: $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(k-1)(k-2)(k-3)\cdot\ldots\cdot(k-n)}{n!z^k}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Find the value of the sum:

> $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(k-1)(k-2)(k-3)\cdot\ldots\cdot(k-n)}{n!z^k}$$

where $n,z>1$ are fixed natural numbers.

I've have constructed this sum, when trying to multiply the sums of infinite geometric series in the form of $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\tfrac{1}{3^k}}$. It is clear that the sum is $\tfrac{1}{2}$. When we multiply such sums n times the product of such infinite sums is equal to $\tfrac{1}{2^n}$. But, it can be written also as: $\left ( \tfrac{1}{3}+\tfrac{1}{3^2}+\tfrac{1}{3^3}+... \right )^2 = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\tfrac{k-1}{3^k}$, then $\left ( \tfrac{1}{3}+\tfrac{1}{3^2}+\tfrac{1}{3^3}+... \right )^3 = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\tfrac{(k-1)(k-2)}{2!3^k}$, $\left ( \tfrac{1}{3}+\tfrac{1}{3^2}+\tfrac{1}{3^3}+... \right )^4 = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\tfrac{(k-1)(k-2)(k-3)}{3!3^k}$. Using elementary math, it can be shown that coefficients in such sums near every $\tfrac{1}{3^k}$ are Pascal's triangle numbers: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 for n=2. 1, 3, 6, 10, 15 for n=3 and so on. Are there a general approach for calculating such sums (pure calculus solution or elementary strict proof) for my problem? I think the answer is always is: $\frac{1}{(z-1)^{n+1}}$. For example, check: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+of+(k-1)(k-2)(k-3)(k-4)(k-5)(k-6)(k-7)(k-8)(k-9)(k-10)%2F(10!*4%5Ek)+k%3D1+to+infinity
It's exactly: $\frac{1}{3^{11}}$

Comment: Please use the [Mathjax guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) instead of links to pictures, as we shouldn't have to go find the problem to begin with.  Secondly, you should show effort to get answers.  That being said, use the binomial theorem here.

Comment: In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say what your thoughts on it are, and what you have tried to solve the problem; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, please try to make the title more descriptive, there are a lot of questions about finding infinite sums.

Comment: @FarrukhAtaev Why would it? The first $n$ terms are zero, then they are $>0$

Comment: Another hint: $k-n=0\forall k\ge n$

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Is that a typo? $k-n\neq 0\forall k\geq n$...

Comment: @JohnDoe Oops, I meant the summand was $0\forall k\ge n$.

Comment: To have your question reopened, I recommend taking the time to learn Mathjax (see comments above), then provide work/what you have tried.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Ah I see - but is it not meant to be $\forall k\leq n$? Since this is when there is a term which is $k-k$.

Comment: Hm... you are right.  I was honestly expecting the plain old binomial theorem where the tail is zero, so I didn't think of it too much @JohnDoe

Comment: You didn't show the "elementary math" that you used, but unless you invoked something special about $\frac13,$ it should work just as well for $\left(\frac1z+\frac1{z^2}+\frac1{z^3}+\ldots\right)^n.$ If so, you will already have proved your value of the sum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a "pure calculus" solution, let's try Taylor series.
Specifically, let's look at the Taylor series of 
$f(x) = \frac{1}{(1-x)^{n+1}}$ around $x=0.$
We have
\begin{align}
f'(x) &= \frac{d}{dx}\frac{1}{(1-x)^{n+1}} 
       = \frac{n+1}{(1-x)^{n+2}}, \\
f''(x) &= \frac{d}{dx}\frac{n+1}{(1-x)^{n+2}} 
       = \frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{(1-x)^{n+3}}, \\
&\vdots\\
f^{(m)}(x) &= \frac{(n+1)(n+2)\cdots(n+m)}{(1-x)^{n+m+1}}. \\
\end{align}

So $f^{(m)}(0) = (n+1)(n+2)\cdots(n+m),$
and the general term of the Taylor series around $x=0$ is 
$$
\frac{f^{(m)}(0)}{m!}x^m  = \frac{(n+1)(n+2)\cdots(n+m)}{m!} x^m 
  = \binom{n+m}{n} x^m
$$
for $m=0,1,2,\ldots.$ That is,
$$
f(x) =  \sum_{m=0}^\infty \binom{n+m}{n} x^m.
$$

Now let $k = n+m+1.$ Then
\begin{align}
f(x) =  \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \binom{k-1}{n} x^{k-n-1}
 &=  \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \frac{(k-1)(k-2)\cdots(k-n)}{n!} x^{k-n-1}\\
 &=  \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(k-1)(k-2)\cdots(k-n)}{n!} x^{k-n-1},
\end{align}
since $(k-1)(k-2)\cdots(k-n)= 0$ for $k=1,2,\ldots,n.$
This converges when $\lvert x \lvert < 1.$

Let $x = \frac1z$ where $\lvert z \lvert > 1.$
Then $\lvert x \lvert < 1$ and 
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{(z-1)^{n+1}} 
&= \frac{1}{\left(\frac1x-1\right)^{n+1}} = \frac{x^{n+1}}{(1-x)^{n+1}}
= x^{n+1} f(x) \\
&= x^{n+1} \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(k-1)(k-2)\cdots(k-n)}{n!} x^{k-n-1}\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(k-1)(k-2)\cdots(k-n)}{n!} x^k\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(k-1)(k-2)\cdots(k-n)}{n! z^k}.\\
\end{align}

We can conclude that whenever $\lvert z \lvert > 1,$
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(k-1)(k-2)\cdots(k-n)}{n! z^k} = 
\frac{1}{(z-1)^{n+1}}. $$

Comment: The series converges for $z\gt1$, so for $n$ even, this formula gives a negative result for the sum of a positive series. This is why I believe it should be $(z-1)^{-n-1}$.

Comment: @robjohn I made a transcription error. About 2/3 of the way through the answer, I wrote $\frac{1}{(z-1)^{n+1}}$ and proceeded to show it equal to the sum, so I should have copied $\frac{1}{(z-1)^{n+1}}$ to the final answer. Now that I have corrected that transcription error, my result agrees with yours and with the OP.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty\frac{(k-1)(k-2)(k-3)\cdot\ldots\cdot(k-n)}{n!z^k}
&=\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty\binom{k-1}{n}z^{-k}\tag{1}\\
&=\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty\binom{k-1}{k-n-1}z^{-k}\tag{2}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{k+n}{k}z^{-k-n-1}\tag{3}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\binom{-n-1}{k}z^{-k-n-1}\tag{4}\\
&=z^{-n-1}\left(1-\frac1z\right)^{-n-1}\tag{5}\\[9pt]
&=(z-1)^{-n-1}\tag{6}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: rewrite with binomial coefficients
$(2)$: $\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n}{n-k}$
$(3)$: substitute $k\mapsto k+n+1$
$(4)$: $\binom{n}{k}=(-1)^k\binom{k-1-n}{k}$
$(5)$: Binomial Theorem
$(6)$: algebra

Answer (score 1):

The sum you are trying to calculate is: $$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{\prod\limits_{i=1}^{n}(k-i)}{n!}z^{-k} = \frac{1}{n!}\sum\limits_{k=n+1}^{+\infty}\prod\limits_{i=1}^{n}(k-i)z^{-k}= \frac{1}{n!}\sum\limits_{k=n+1}^{+\infty}\frac{(k-1)!}{(k-n-1)!}z^{-k}.$$

Now, notice that, for $k>n$, $$\frac{\partial^{n}}{\partial z^{n}} z^{n-k}=\frac{\partial^{n-1}}{\partial z^{n-1}} (n-k)z^{n-k-1}= \cdots = (-1)^{n}\frac{(k-1)!}{(k-n-1)!}z^{-k}.$$

Hence, the sum becomes: $$\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n!}\sum\limits_{k=n+1}^{+\infty}\frac{\partial^{n}}{\partial z^{n}}z^{n-k}=\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n!}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{\partial^{n}}{\partial z^{n}}z^{-k}.$$

Furthermore, as $z>1$: $$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{\partial^{n}}{\partial z^{n}}z^{-k} = \frac{\partial^{n}}{\partial z^{n}}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{+\infty}z^{-k} = \frac{\partial^{n}}{\partial z^{n}} \left(\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{z}}-1 \right) = \frac{\partial^{n}}{\partial z^{n}}\frac{1}{z-1}=\frac{(-1)^{n}(n)!}{(z-1)^{n+1}}. $$

Therefore, your result is: $$\frac{1}{(z-1)^{n+1}}$$

Comment: I haven't found out why, but somehow this gets an answer different from the other three results (question and two other answers) which all agree with each other.

Comment: Thanks I had made a small mistake in my derivation and corrected it now.